# Constructing new object after deleting property in a custom function?

Tags: javascript

Im struggling with a challenge problem that I think I have nearly solved. My first issue is the format of the input data, aka coupons, seems to be csv, not json. I know D3 can convert easily but im too used to working with json to have thought of a solution.

How the input data looks like (csv likely): https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZYNu.jpg

The second issue is I'm not sure how to construct a new array of objects that remove a property on each object. In this case I want to delete the code property on the object. I will give an example of what an object would look like:

```
const exData = [{
"upc":"9131891630585208",
"code":"30417547581177009338",
"category":"Gift Cards",
"itemPrice":"19.82",
"couponAmount":"2.74"  
}]

function personalizedList(coupons, preferredCategories) {
      const filteredByCategory = coupons.filter( coupon =>   
                                  coupon.category === preferredCategories);
      const sorted = filteredByCategory.sort( 
                            (a,b) => b.couponAmount - a.couponAmount );
      const topTen = sorted.slice(0,9);

      //help here. Thinking about using forEach to construct a new obj 
      //but I want to remove one of the properties in my output, aka 
     // something like delete coupon.code on each object in my topTen
}
```

Comment: so, you want to format a `json` out of the crap load of data ? so you could delete any  property you want after that ?

Comment: So you have an array of objects, and you want to return an array of top 10 objects and remove `code` property?

Comment: RaphaMex, yes

George Baily: Sadly yes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `forEach` and `delete` to do this in the most efficient way:

```
// Build an array of objects, some with a `bam` key that we want to remove
arrayOfStuff = [{ foo: 'keep this', bam: 'remove this' }, { foo: 'keep this' }]

// Delete anything with a `bam` key in the array of objects
arrayOfStuff.forEach(i => delete i.bam)

// Return completed array
arrayOfStuff
```

The output of these operations looks something like this:

```
[
  { foo: 'keep this' },
  { foo: 'keep this' }
]
```

Which I think is what you're after?

Comment: If I wanted to filter the coupons based off an array of categories would iti be something like this?

const filteredByCategories = coupons.filter( (coupon, i) => coupon.category === preferredCategories.includes(i) );